# Launch a script on a separate server from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app, when a user clicks a button it will currently launch an in-house created script in the background. For simplicity, let's just call it `myScript`. So in my Rails app, I basically have:

```
def run!
  `myScript with some arguments`
end
```

Now this script will run as a process on the same machine that the Rails application is running on.

We want to host all of our Ruby/Rails apps on one server, and utilize a separate server for running the scripts. Is it possible to launch that script, but on a different machine? Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: I can think of 2 ways: Use SSH to login and execute a command, like `ssh user@host -- myscript with some arguments`, or create an HTTP server on that machine and send normal GET/POST requests (with some auth).

Comment: I'm familiar with SSH, but not inside of an application. You can SSH within ruby?

Comment: You can either use [net-ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) (pure ruby solution), or just call the command line `ssh` command like you are calling `myScript` above.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this some thought and talk it over with my team. I'll leave this question open for now to see if anyone else has other ideas. Thanks much.

Comment: Personally I'll suggest creating a lightweight app on the other server (using Sinatra maybe), and calling it like you call any other remote API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use ssh for these types of things.

```
require 'net/ssh'
Net::SSH.start('server.com', 'username', password: "asdasd") do |ssh|
  $stdout.print ssh.exec!("cdc && curl https://gist.github.com/mhenrixon/asdasd123123/raw/123123asdasd/update.rb | rails c production")
end
```

That's the easiest way of doing it I think but the sinatra/rails listener isn't a bad idea either.

Comment: +1 ; if you want to run this on another server with your Rails environment, you need to make sure your app is installed there, and then use script/runner to start the script

Comment: if you set up your ssh-keys correctly, you can login without using a password

Comment: I am marking this one as correct because it is the method I am going with at the moment. We do not want to install a web server on the other machine at this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To flat out steal Dogbert's answer: I'd go with a HTTP solution. Create a background job (Sidekick, Queue Classic) and have a simple job that does a get or a post or whatever on that second server.

The HTTP solution will involve a bit of a setup cost (time and learning probably) but in the end it will be a bit more robust than the SSH solution as you won't have to worry about IPs or users,etc. just a straight up URL. Plus if you are doing things with Capistrano,etc your deployments will be super easy.

Is there a reason why these jobs couldn't be run on the your webserver, but with a background process?