# Launching C executable via ruby script on Ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, ubuntu

I have a situation I need some assistance with. It involves ruby, rails, and a native c applications running on an Ubuntu server.

I am able to compile the c applications on the server and now need to know how to launch them via ruby script.

My end goal is to take lists of data from a rails app, save them to a specific .dat file on the server, use this file as the input to my executables (along with flags), and load the resulting files back through a ruby script into my rails app for display.

I'm currently looking at these to start:

[Confirm existance of executable (script, bat, cmd, exe) via a ruby file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969967/confirm-existance-of-executable-script-bat-cmd-exe-via-a-ruby-file)

[Launch a script on a separate server from a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059856/launch-a-script-on-a-separate-server-from-a-rails-app)

[Confirm existance of executable (script, bat, cmd, exe) via a ruby file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969967/confirm-existance-of-executable-script-bat-cmd-exe-via-a-ruby-file)

[Ruby require_relative executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252542/ruby-require-relative-executing-script)

If anyone has done anything like this or has ideas of how to do it please advise.

Comment: In ruby you can run native code surrounded with back tick characters ` ``ls /home``. So then you need write parser that will parse result from previous code and create your ruby models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
original_file_path = 'path/to/original_file.dat'
modified_file_path = 'path/to/modified_file.dat'

File.write(file_path, 'data')

#this will return an output from c program
#use this if you need to parse output from c program
result = `some_c_executable --some_flag #{file_path}`
#parsing result...
data = File.read(modified_file_path)
#work with data
```

Or

```
#if you don't need output from c program, use "system"
#it returns you true or false according to success
result = system "some_c_executable --some_flag #{file_path}"
if result
  data = File.read(modified_file_path)
  #work with data
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: This pretty much answers my question. Thanks Serj!